# Laravel get name of file

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-5.1

I basically just want to get the name of a file which I get like this:

```
$inputPdf = $request->file('input_pdf');
```

if I `dd($inputPdf)` it prints me `null`.

Comment: The input was empty (no file given) or you are no getting the correct input name.

Comment: It might be useful you provide related HTML, or any information. For now, it's not possible to say more than: there is no file. We don't know what you are doing in your browser, what your html looks like, or anything like that.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

1. To get the file name, as mentioned in the docs:

> You may access uploaded files that are included with the Illuminate\Http\Request instance using the file method. The object returned by the file method is an instance of the Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile class, which extends the PHP SplFileInfo class and provides a variety of methods for interacting with the file
>
> There are a variety of other methods available on UploadedFile instances. Check out the [API documentation for the class](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) for more information regarding these methods.

So you can use this method: `getClientOriginalName()`

http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName

```
$request->file('input_pdf')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Would return the file name.

You can do this to check if the file exists before calling any methods on it:

```
if ($request->hasFile('input_pdf')) {
    return $request->file('input_pdf')->getClientOriginalName();
} else {
    return 'no file!'
}
```

2. To solve the issue of `dd($request->file('input_pdf'))` returning `null` check you are using the correct name for the file. You can try `dd($request)` and you will see if there are any files in it. You can check the file name when reviewing the dump of the `Request` object.

Comment: This returns me Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Comment: Which means there was no object returned by using the `file()` method. `$request->file('input_pdf')` returned null, so you're essentially trying to call `getClientOriginalName()` on null. Try `dd($request)` and you will see if there are any files in it. Perhaps you got the wrong name?

Comment: Are you also passing the `Request $request` in your method?

Comment: See my answer's update for checking file is in the request

Comment: Can you `dd($request)` and paste the output @JohnDoesLegacy?

Comment: Include your form html with file input, if you're updating your question

Comment: Because none of you read the question entirely: you proposed something which was not relevant: there is no file. Period. This was the main problem, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The question mentions: "if I dd it prints me null." Which means that calling any method obviously will give the error OP reported in first comment on both answers.

Comment: @Arcesilas thanks for leaving the comment, I genuinely didn't read the sentence after the code that reads "if I dd it prints me null." and your downvote is valid. Unless he edited that in afterwards?

Comment: No, it was here the first time i opened the question. The question has not been edited at all.

Comment: Ok I think I got it liike you guys said the name of an input was wrong just a syntax thing instead of _ I wrote - I tick this one if it is ok for you

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. I'll add the comment I made regarding the issue that fixed it to my answer.

Comment: @Arcesilas the updated answer now addresses both parts of the question, thanks

Comment: And thanks again for your comment when I asked about the downvote. Will remind me to read the question properly before answering!

Answer (score 13):

```
$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
```

[Check this](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) for more methods.

Comment: This returns me Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Comment: Ensure you are posting a file, you can see the contents of the request object by doing dd($request). Also ensure your form (on the front end) is accepting file input (enctype)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

In your form. Or if you used laravel HTML service provider use

```
{!! Form::open(array('files' => true)) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using it

Comment: Can you please add more code snippet like your controller method and html.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you have use the correct input name.**

```html
<input type="file" name="image">

$request->image->getClientOriginalName();
```