# Get File Uploading Field name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Trying Get Field name of Uploading Files..
Like in PHP

```
 reset($_FILES);
 $field_name = key($_FILES);
```

How to do Same in Laravel...Please Only Laravel Code for Same Purpose..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: just loop the $request value which instance of Files

Comment: This is helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161505/laravel-get-name-of-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done Following Code Given field name

```
 $field_name =  key($request->file());
```