# Why do I get a null in return when trying to store file path name in database?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm not sure why I'm getting `null` in return when trying to test if my endpoint works.

The table name's correct but for some reason, it isn't recognizing my file.  My table as has more than one column despite my code and was created with `php artisan`.  (I'm just trying to populate `filePath` column, I'll work on others later).  Below's an image for reference
[image]

If I get rid of the `dd($filePath);` which's in my controller - the Postman errors returns:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'file_path' cannot be null (SQL: insert into` photos `(`file_path`) values (?))`

Note:  My Laravel code base and React.js code base are completely separated.  Anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Here's my frontend code:

```
fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
        selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
    })
}

fileUploadHandler = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
    axios.post('http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame', fd)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
}

<form action="http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame" encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form">
            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}/>
            <button onClick={this.fileUploadHandler}>Upload</button>
        </form>
```

Here's my php controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $filePath = $request->input('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $data=array('file_path'=>$filePath);

    // dd($filePath);

    DB::table('photos')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    echo '<a href = "/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the react code but normally `<form action="http://myendpoint/api/auth/wall-of-fame" id="login-form" className="form">` wouldn't submit a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean would be needed

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161505/laravel-get-name-of-file.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov thanks for sharing.  I tried what's suggested but now I'm getting `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null in file`.  I'm really not sure what's going on.  I've updated my controller code.

Comment: Your form is missing this attr: enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov forgot to mention I've tried that as well but still get the same result :(

Comment: I assume you want to upload a file and insert the file's name in DB?
Please, check this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_file_uploading.htm.

Comment: Change `$request->input('file')` to `$request->file('file')`

Comment: @cloudyday when you did dd() on filePath does it return the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrive a file from **Request**, use the `file` method instead of `input` method :

```
$filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

You may determine if a file is present on the request using the `hasFile` method:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

See the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

Comment: Thanks man this was it, I'm getting expected result in `dd()`!  Now I need to figure out why the file name won't get stored in DB.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you :)